# Can I get an array with Jquery $.post?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I using jquery's $.post to pull information from a database dynamically. This works fine if I want one item however, I would like to store each column as an array and pass the whole array over. I have the array but am having issues pulling it back to javascript so I can use it.

Since the array will contain text with commas I can't use implode to create a comma separated string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using json, if you use php's json_encode on the array on the server side then echo the encoded array jquery will pick it up as a json object.

Answer (score 0):

You must append the "json" like this:

```
$.post("/your/page", dict,
 function(data) {
  dosomething();

}, "json");
```

then you can use the .each for looping

```
jQuery.each(data, function(i, val) {
 alert(i);
 alert(val);

});
```

or reference values by keys like this:

```
data['key']
```

You need to use an associative array. 
Also, it is required that the data returned by /your/page is JSON encoded (for PHP see [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php))